# Why can't I launch viewModel() two times when I use Hilt as DI in an Android Studio project?

Tags: android, dagger-hilt

I use *Hilt* as DI in an Android Studio project, and `viewModel()` will create an instance of `SoundViewModel` automatically.

Code A works well.

I think `viewModel()` will create an Singleton of `SoundViewModel`.

I think  `mViewMode_A` will be assigned to `mViewMode_B` automatically without creating  a new instance in Code B.

I think both `mViewMode_A` and  `mViewMode_B` will point the same instance in Code B.

But I don't know why I get Result B when I run Code B, could you tell me?

**Result B**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class info.dodata.soundmeter.presentation.viewmodel.SoundViewModel
```

**Code A**

```
@Composable
fun NavGraph( 
    mViewModel_A: SoundViewModel = viewModel()
) {
    ScreenHome(mViewMode_B = mViewMode1_A)      
}



@Composable
fun ScreenHome(
    mViewModel_B: SoundViewModel
 
) {
   ...  
}


@HiltViewModel
class SoundViewModel @Inject constructor(
    @ApplicationContext private val appContext: Context,
    ...
): ViewModel() {
   ...
  
}
```

**Code B**

```
@Composable
fun NavGraph( 
    mViewMode_A: SoundViewModel = viewModel()
) {
    ScreenHome()      
}



@Composable
fun ScreenHome(
    mViewMode_B: SoundViewModel = viewModel()  // I think  mViewMode_A will be assigned to mViewMode_B automatically without creating  a new instnace.
 
) {
   ...  
}

//The same
```

Comment: if you are using Hilt DI, then plese use `hiltViewModel()` instead of `viewModel()`.

Comment: Thanks! But `hiltViewModel()` doesn't  work.

Comment: @AagitoEx I've never heard of the `hiltViewModel()` function. Can you provide a link to the documentation where you found this solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the key in ViewModel initialization

I'm not good at Composable but this will resolve your problem

For creating a new instance of ViewModel we need to set Key property

```
ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(<UniqueKey>, SoundViewModel::class.java)
```

key – The key to use to identify the ViewModel.

```
val mViewMode_A = viewModel<SoundViewModel>(key = "NavGraph")
val mViewMode_B = viewModel<SoundViewModel>(key = "ScreenHome")
```

For Composable this link may help you [separateViewmodel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69757251/3522570)