# How to have one viewmodel and one composable but different data from viewmodel?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-viewmodel

I have top tab view. Each tab returns same composable that shows list of different posts. Initially i fetch tabs and data initial data for each tab. It looks like this:

```
@Composable
fun Feed() {
    val tabsViewModel: TabsViewModel = hiltViewModel()
    val tabs = tabsViewModel.state.collectAsState()
    val communityFieldViewModel: CommunityFeedViewModel = hiltViewModel()
    val selectedTab = tabsViewModel.selectedTab.collectAsState()
    val indexOfTile = tabs.value.indexOfFirst { it.id == selectedTab.value }
    if(tabs.value.isNotEmpty()) {
        var tabIndex by remember { mutableStateOf(indexOfTile) }
        Column {
            TabRow(selectedTabIndex = tabIndex) {
                tabs.value.forEachIndexed { index, tab ->
                    communityFieldViewModel.loadInitialState(tab.id, tab.tiles, "succeed", tab.token)
                    Tab(selected = tabIndex == index,
                        onClick = { tabIndex = index },
                        text = { Text(text = tab.title) })
                }
            }
            tabs.value.forEachIndexed { _, tab ->
                CommunityFeed(tab.id)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My CommunityFeed is getting data from CommunityFeedViewModel and I set initial data for CommunityFeedViewModel in Feed. But problem is that I do not know how to get different data in CommunityFeed and now both render for example all posts and should be different. Here is CommunityFeed and CommunityFeedModel. Any advice?

```
data class CommunityState(
    val path: String = "",
    val tiles: List<Tile> = emptyList(),
    val loadingState: String = "idle",
    val token: String? = null
)
@HiltViewModel
class CommunityFeedViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val tileRepository: TileRepository,
): ViewModel() {
    private val state = MutableStateFlow(CommunityState())
    val modelState = state.asStateFlow()
    fun loadInitialState(path: String, tiles: List<Tile>?, loadingState: String, token: String?) {
        val tileList = tiles ?: emptyList()
        state.value = CommunityState(path, tileList, loadingState, token)
    }
}
```

```
@Composable
fun CommunityFeed(path: String) {
    val feedViewModel: CommunityFeedViewModel = hiltViewModel()
    val state = feedViewModel.modelState.collectAsState()
    if(state.value.path == path) {
        TileListView(tiles = state.value.tiles, loadMore = {})
    }
}
```

Comment: [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) shouldn't be a repo, it should be only code that can fit here - you can use fake data, e.g. in your example instead of running a query just return static data.

Comment: How do you expect to display different data depending on tag, if you only have a single `modelState`?

Comment: To create different view models for each tab you can use method showed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69371176/3585796)

Comment: `communityFieldViewModel.loadInitialState` running such method from Composable is a bad practice, as per [Thinking in Compose](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/mental-model) all composables should be free of side-effects (which is calling `loadInitialState`). The cleanest way is calling this method in view model `init` block, if you need to re-run it when the view appears, wrap it with `LaunchedEffect`.  More info can be found in side effects [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects#launchedeffect)

Comment: Ok I will try to add fake data @PhilDukhov. Every tab basically will get same data and those are posts. For example tab a get all posts, tab b get posts from people you follow etc. I tried to use solution to create different view models and it does not return any updated data at all. In the end I need to use single composable that returns list of tiles and view model that will serve different posts to tab.

Comment: And how to run it inside init block of viewmodel because i need to wait data to come first. Sorry maybe I am just completely wrong here :(

Comment: how is it getting loaded? why do you need to pass any data from composable? Looks like you have `tileRepository`, in your view model you should subscribe to updates from this repository

Comment: I am loading first tabs from server. I get model in response json object like
{selectedTab: 'all-posts', tabs:[{id: "all-posts", tiles: [], token: null}, {id: "following", tiles: [{id: "1", text: "Boom"}],  token: "123"}]
And I need set initial data for each tab and when want to load more i use token. Problem is single composable and single viewmodel to handle all of those cases.

Comment: @PhilDukhov here is gist with all components and sample data. https://gist.github.com/Jalson1982/8187f6e10fefded551f3e43392d4481f

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245549/discussion-between-jalson1982-and-phil-dukhov).

Comment: Nah I need just to find way to pass initial parameters to my hilt viewmodel and all will be good :)

Comment: I'm not sure how you can do that with Hilt - it doesn't support a factory like a plain view model does. The only way I know is using `SavedStateHandle`, but it would require each tab to be a separate destination in navigation controller - which is not a bad thing after all